# Prophet Muhammad SAW praying for his ummah on the day of judgement

Tags: hadith

I had that on the day of judgement, when sun is one mile above our head, that people will be suffering and looking for who will rescue them for the suffering, and they will go to prophet Muhammad SAW and he will pray to Allah SWT to save his ummah.

My question is, is this narration right and is in which Hadith, I try all my best to get the Hadith but am unable to get it, maybe you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are probably many hadith for this. One of them is this one.

> ....Anas then said, "Muhammad talked to us saying, 'On the Day of
> Resurrection the people will surge with each other like waves, and
> then they will come to Adam and say, 'Please intercede for us with
> your Lord.' He will say, 'I am not fit for that but you'd better go to
> Abraham as he is the Khalil of the Beneficent.' They will go to
> Abraham and he will say, 'I am not fit for that, but you'd better go
> to Moses as he is the one to whom Allah spoke directly.' So they will
> go to Moses and he will say, 'I am not fit for that, but you'd better
> go to Jesus as he is a soul created by Allah and His Word.' (Be: And
> it was) they will go to Jesus and he will say, 'I am not fit for that,
> but you'd better go to Muhammad.' They would come to me and I would
> say, 'I am for that.' Then I will ask for my Lord's permission, and it
> will be given, and then He will inspire me to praise Him with such
> praises as I do not know now. So I will praise Him with those praises
> and will fall down, prostrate before Him. Then it will be said, 'O
> Muhammad, raise your head and speak, for you will be listened to; and
> ask, for your will be granted (your request); and intercede, for your
> intercession will be accepted.' I will say, 'O Lord, my followers! My
> followers!' And then it will be said, 'Go and take out of Hell (Fire)
> all those who have faith in their hearts, equal to the weight of a
> barley grain.' I will go and do so and return to praise Him with the
> same praises, and fall down (prostrate) before Him. Then it will be
> said, 'O Muhammad, raise your head and speak, for you will be listened
> to, and ask, for you will be granted (your request); and intercede,
> for your intercession will be accepted.' I will say, 'O Lord, my
> followers! My followers!' It will be said, 'Go and take out of it all
> those who have faith in their hearts equal to the weight of a small
> ant or a mustard seed.' I will go and do so and return to praise Him
> with the same praises, and fall down in prostration before Him. It
> will be said, 'O, Muhammad, raise your head and speak, for you will be
> listened to, and ask, for you will be granted (your request)....

You can read the full hadith in [Sahih al-Bukhari 7510](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/135)